# Facebook .net Application Development

Tags: .net, asp.net, facebook, fbml

Whats the best starting point for facebook application development in .net?

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question - you're not really saying what you want to do with your app.  The obvious starting point would be the Facebook API, but beyond that there's not much to be offered...

Comment: i don't want to use the conventional facebook api. I need .net wrappers, unlike php .net cannot connect directly, they need wrappers or you do a webclient call.

Comment: It should be noted that php doesn't connect "directly" to Facebook either.  They have to access wrappers to the Facebook API just like everyone else.  It just might be that they have some more standardized wrappers for php than they do for .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) is pretty comprehensive, and covers a number of scenarios, from creating your own hosted Facebook app, to libraries for interacting with Facebook APIs.

Comment: This answer is no longer "correct".  That toolkit is no longer supported.  People should be using the Facebook C# SDK - http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Download and look through [facebooksharp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/FacebookSharp)
It is one of most complete APIs(with support of old api and new facebook graph api)
If you'll get troubles with auth - feel free to contact.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph Toolkit at http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/ will help you a lot.